# Quick intersection question.

Tags: linear-algebra

What's the answer to this: $ \{(1,0),(0,0)\} \cap \{(2,0),(0,0)\} $ = ?

I thought it might be $ \{(0,0)\}$ But I guess it's wrong and I'm missing the first x-axis vector which should be in the answer too. Anyone, please?

Comment: Your answer is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is indeed $\{(0,0)\}$.  When taking intersections of sets, it doesn't matter really what the elements of those sets 'represent', it just matters whether they're in both sets or not.  So there would be no reason here to even consider the fact that they are ordered pairs.